# 2-Tier Architecture (DataBase)

Tags: database, architecture, 2-tier

I was reading about the difference between the tiers of architecture (2 and 3). I got to know that the later was safer than the first. The 2 Tier poses security risks, a website said. I am unable to understand what security risks the 2 tier architecture could pose?

I took the example of a ticketing software that used to have a 2 tier system. Now, if multiple clients are sending queries, can one client access information of the other one? can the response to the request get mixed up, sending wrong information to each of the clients?

I am unable to think of security issues which could exist. It would be great if anybody could drop in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In a two tier system, clients are accessing a database directly.  An improperly secured database could grant too much access to a client. Securing databases for public access takes quite a bit of work. They are general execution systems and are not generally designed with fine grained security systems (exceptions do exist).

Three tier systems generally do not expose general execution systems to clients.  They have specific methods and securing the middle tier is generally much more straightforward.